# JavaScript not executing inside script tag

Tags: javascript, html

This is extremely embarrassing as this is probably the simplest code you'll ever see that someone could be having a problem with; I have this simple html document:

```
<script>
    function rollDie() {
        let result = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
        return result < 1 ? result + 1 : result;
    }

    function updateView() {
        let getResult = rollDie();
        console.log(getResult);
        document.getElementById('d6-a').innerHTML = getResult;
    }
</script>
<input id='d6-a' name="d6-a" type='submit' onsubmit="updateView" />
```

That's it -- literally just that. Yes that's the whole document. No <!DOCTYPE>, no <html>, no <head>, no <body>; but I was (and still am) under the impression that that is all fine and any modern browser should compile, render and run this with no issue regardless.

And it does render just fine; but when I click the input nothing happens. The HTML is not updated and nothing is logged in the console (not even any errors). Which tells me the scripts are just being straight ignored, but why? I have tried: moving the <script> to the bottom of the document, onsubmit="updateView", onsubmit="updateView()", onclick (each as before), changing the input element to <button> (how I originally had it), changing the input element to <div>. It. Doesn't. Work. Please help? (I'm using Google Chrome btw)

Comment: Input element has no submit event

Comment: Also `<input>` elements do not have content, so `.innerHTML` won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

onsubmit is not applicable for input tag.You should wrap it in a form element & the onsubmit event handler must be added to form element.

```
<form onsubmit="updateView()">
        <input id='d6-a' name="d6-a" type='submit'  />
    </form>
```